# Gradle: what is the task structure for native builds (cpp plugin)?

Tags: gradle, native, gradle-task

For Java builds (plugin "java"), there exists this very nice image about halfway through [the Java Plugin page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) showing the normal workflow of a java build.

[image]

Question: what would be the similar illustration for the native ("cpp") plugin? The [Building Native Software page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html#sec:native_tasks) has an extensive discussion about "check" tasks and custom "check tasks" but where are the others? and how do they interact? I found only a brief mention that indeed there exists *"a set of other tasks that do the actual work of compiling, linking or assembling the binary"*.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Oddly enough I wasn't even looking for this, I found it by accident and remembered seeing your question here earlier today. I hope this helps, it was found [here](https://github.com/Tocea/gradle-cpp-plugin/blob/master/README.md).